# Нажатие на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть код

```html
<div class="column_3" id="hidden_link" onclick="window.location.href=location.href='submit';" style="display:yes">
содержимое
</div>
```

Хотел сделать так что бы при нажатии в любом месте блока, автоматически нажималась и кнопка регистрации. Блок сделать ссылкой получилось, но при нажатии переходит по адрусу сайт.ру/submit и ошибка 404.
 Как сделать чтобы при нажатии в блоке нажималась и кнопка регистрации?

Comment: Добавьте больше кода, так как не понятно, как у вас начинается регистрация.

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin, что ещё вам нужно после этого увидеть ©`location.href='submit'`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var block=document.getElementById("block");
var btn=document.getElementById("btn");

block.addEventListener("click",blockClick);
btn.addEventListener("click",btnClick);

function btnClick() {
  console.log("btnClick");
}

function blockClick() {
  console.log("blockClick");
  btn.click();
}
```

```css
#block{
  cursor:pointer;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border:1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="block">block</div>
<button id="btn">button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Как сделать чтобы при нажатии в блоке нажималась и кнопка регистрации?

Вот такой пример:

```js
var blk = document.querySelector(".blk");
var btn = document.querySelector(".btn")
// Вешаем событие на кнопку
btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Не отсылает на сервер
  console.log('Button clicked');
})
// Вешаем событие на блок
blk.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  btn.click(); // Вызываем событие кнопки
  console.log('Block is clicked');
});
```

```css
.blk {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="blk">Some block</div>
<!-------- Кнопка для submit -------->
<button class="btn" type='submit'>button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Использование события нажатия мыши `.click()` это не очень хорошая идея, по тому что некоторые браузеры воспримут это поведение за XSS атаку. Вместо этого вам следует генерировать событие `.submit()`.

```js
var background = document.getElementById("background");
var form = document.getElementById("background");

background.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  form.submit();
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  width: 40%;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <div id="background">
    <button id="button">Кнопка</button>
  </div>
</form>
```